# Python: How do I get multiple results in the same excel sheet?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a data set consisting of 10 columns and I am currently using the groupby() function to get averages of the first 6 columns and then using groupby() to get min and max values of the other 4 columns. The issue is when I try to put the results into a new excel sheet, I keep getting errors that 'list' object has no attribute 'to_excel'

```
avg = df.groupby('column1')[['column2' , 'column3', 'column4' ,'column5',  'column6',  'column7' ]].mean()

c8= (df.assign(c8=df['column8'].abs())
       .groupby(['column1'])['column8'].agg([('min' , 'min'), ('max', 'max')])
       .add_prefix('c8'))

c9= (df.assign(c9=df['column9'].abs())
       .groupby(['column1'])['column9'].agg([('min' , 'min'), ('max', 'max')])
       .add_prefix('c9'))

c10= (df.assign(c10=df['column'].abs())
       .groupby(['column1'])['column10'].agg([('min' , 'min'), ('max', 'max')])
       .add_prefix('c10'))


df = [avg , c8, c9, c10]

#print(df)

wb = pd.ExcelWriter('C:filepath.xlsx' , engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(wb,sheet_name='Results')
wb.save()
```

Whenever I run any of the functions by themselves, they all work fine, the issue is when I put them together.

What I am expecting is an excel sheet filled with the corresponding data presented like this:

```
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6 column7 c8min c8max c9min c9max c10min c10max
```

Comment: `to_excel` is a method of a `DataFrame`. You have a list. `df = [avg , c8, c9, c10]` is a list of DataFrames.

Comment: Is there a method for lists similar to to_excel?

Comment: Perhaps the question you need to be asking is: how to create a `DataFrame` from `avg`, `c8`, `c9`, and `c10`?

Comment: Yes, I am fairly new to python and am open to learning better ways to code in it. How would I go about creating a dataframe from avg , c8 , c9 , c10?

Comment: You might consider `pd.concat`?

Comment: something like this:  df(pd.concat([avg, c8, c9, c10], 
                  axis = 1  ))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252757/discussion-between-amber-l-and-bigben).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way with [`GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html?highlight=agg#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg) in a *single shot* :

```
fmin = lambda x: abs(x).min()
fmax = lambda x: abs(x).max()

out = (
        df.groupby("column1", as_index=False)
          .agg(column2=("column2", "mean"), column3=("column3", "mean"),
               column4=("column4", "mean"), column5=("column5", "mean"),
               column6=("column6", "mean"), column7=("column7", "mean"), # avg
               c8min=("column8", fmin), c8max=("column8", fmax), # c8
               c9min=("column9", fmin), c9max=("column9", fmax), # c9
               c10min=("column10", fmin), c10max=("column10", fmax)) # c10
)


out.to_excel("C:/filepath.xlsx", sheet_name="Results", index=False)
```

Or following your approach, you can use [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to avoid the `AttributeError` :

```
list_dfs = [avg , c8, c9, c10]

(pd.concat(list_dfs, axis=1).reset_index()
    .to_excel("C:/filepath.xlsx", sheet_name="Results", index=False))
```

By the way, why you're assigning the new columns `cx` and not using them ? I suppose you want something like :

```
#Example with c8
c8= (df.assign(c8=df["column8"].abs())
       .groupby(["column1"])["c8"].agg([("min" , "min"), ("max", "max")])
       .add_prefix("c8"))
```